Linking CUDA device functions
I have this a.cu file:
extern "C" __device__ int test42();
__global__ void get42(int* toStore){
    *toStore = test42();
}

int main() {
    int host{0};
    int* device;
    cudaMalloc(&device, sizeof(int));
    get42<<<1, 1>>>(device);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(&host, device, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

and this b.cu file:
extern "C" __device__ int test42(){
    return 42;
}

I compiled b.cu into a fatbinary stored at somepath/b.fatbin.
I have also linked both a.cu and b.cu object files:
nvcc -arch=sm_60 -dlink -o c.o somepath/b.fatbin a.cu  

The object dump clearly shows both functions defined:
$: cuobjdump -sass c.o

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_60
code version = [1,7]
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_60
                Function : test42
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_TEXMODE_UNIFIED EF_CUDA_64BIT_ADDRESS EF_CUDA_SM60 EF_CUDA_VIRTUAL_SM(EF_CUDA_SM60)"
                                                            /* 0x001ffc00ffe007f0 */
        /*0008*/                   MOV32I R4, 0x2a ;        /* 0x0100000002a7f004 */
        /*0010*/                   RET ;                    /* 0xe32000000007000f */
        /*0018*/                   BRA 0x18 ;               /* 0xe2400fffff87000f */
                                                            /* 0x001f8000fc0007e0 */
        /*0028*/                   NOP;                     /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*0030*/                   NOP;                     /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*0038*/                   NOP;                     /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                ..........


                Function : _Z5get42Pi
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_TEXMODE_UNIFIED EF_CUDA_64BIT_ADDRESS EF_CUDA_SM60 EF_CUDA_VIRTUAL_SM(EF_CUDA_SM60)"
                                                            /* 0x001fc400ffa007f6 */
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20] ;   /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
        /*0010*/                   JCAL 0x0 ;               /* 0xe220000000000040 */
        /*0018*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x140] ;  /* 0x4c98078005070002 */
                                                            /* 0x001fbc00fe2007f2 */
        /*0028*/                   MOV R3, c[0x0][0x144] ;  /* 0x4c98078005170003 */
        /*0030*/                   STG.E [R2], R4 ;         /* 0xeedc200000070204 */
        /*0038*/                   NOP ;                    /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                                                            /* 0x001ffc00fc6007ef */
        /*0048*/                   NOP ;                    /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*0050*/                   NOP ;                    /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*0058*/                   EXIT ;                   /* 0xe30000000007000f */
                                                            /* 0x001f8000fc0007ff */
        /*0068*/                   BRA 0x60 ;               /* 0xe2400fffff07000f */
        /*0070*/                   NOP;                     /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*0078*/                   NOP;                     /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */

when I try to build an executable:
nvcc -arch=sm_60 -o executable a.cu c.o -lcudadevrt
I get:
ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function 'test42'

What am I missing?

I don’t understand the build process you are showing at all. It looks at first inspection you are compiling a.cu twice.

This is a simple test for linking device code from some other file. a.cu is compiled not to an executable, but to object file that is linked to the fatbin of b.cu. I want to link the device function declaration in a.cu to the implementation in b.cu. The content of these particular files is just a simplification. If you know a better way to statically link device functions, please share.

I added printf ("host=%d\n", host); at the end of your host code in a.cu. I then built on my ancient Windows 7 web-browsing computer as follows: nvcc -arch=sm_30 -c -rdc=true -o a.obj a.cu; nvcc -arch=sm_30 -c -rdc=true -o b.obj b.cu; nvcc -arch=sm_30 -o test.exe a.obj b.obj; When I run test.exe it prints host=42. Except for differences in customary filename suffixes, it should work exactly like this on Linux, too.

A device link is an operation that generally should only be performed once (for any particular file/module.  It is acceptable to perform multiple device links in a project as long as the files for each device link belong to disjoint sets).
When you did the -dlink step, you performed that device link.  However in your final compilation command, you are neither specifying device-linking (which would presumably be necessary to connect the a.cu supplied at the final compilation command, to the object that has b.cu in it), nor would it be sensible to do so: it's already been done.
So your device link step was premature.
Furthermore, a .fatbin file can only be fed into a device-link step, it cannot be used for ordinary compilation or final link stage.
The net of this is that you would need to use a.cu twice (which is what you were showing) but that is unworkable.
Of course, one possible solution is to do all-at-once compilation and linking:
nvcc -arch=sm_60 a.cu b.cu -rdc=true -o executable

As njuffa has already indicated, you can also separate this into stages.  It seems however that you want to have a preliminary device-linked static object, that you can then link later to an executable.  That should be possible.
A possible solution is to separate out the items in a.cu that could be used to create the executable from the items in a.cu that are definitely necessary for device linking.  One of the examples here may be instructive ("If you want to invoke the device and host linker separately, you can do:").  So the following should work:
# cat a1.cu
extern "C" __device__ int test42();
__global__ void get42(int* toStore){
    *toStore = test42();
}

# cat a2.cu
__global__ void get42(int*);
int main() {
    int host{0};
    int* device;
    cudaMalloc(&device, sizeof(int));
    get42<<<1, 1>>>(device);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(&host, device, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}
# cat b.cu
extern "C" __device__ int test42(){
    return 42;
}
# nvcc -dc a1.cu
# nvcc -dc b.cu
# nvcc -dlink a1.o b.o -o c.o
# nvcc a2.cu a1.o b.o c.o -o executable
#

Note that no device-linking is specified at the final command stage.  If you don't want to carry around a1.o and b.o to the final link step, you could put them in a library (e.g. nvcc -lib ... or ar ...).  But as far as I know there is no way to avoid providing (in some fashion) a1.o, b.o, and c.o, at this final link stage.
